# AWS Elastic beanstalk EC2 instance cannot be accessed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my asp.net mvc application hosted on aws elastic beanstalk. I used aws toolkit for visual studio to deploy my application. There were no errors or anything.

But I get connection time out error when I go to the URL or with the Elastic IP.
it's security group is configured to allow all traffic from all sources to all ports. But still I get the error.

It is subnet and vpc are configured same as my other instances, so I don't know why it is happening..

Please help[image: aws screenshot]

Comment: Have you set KeyPair for the instance? Its not shown on the screenshot.

Comment: Yes I have set the key pair

Comment: Have Network ACLs been modified to perhaps block connections? Also I guess you are using a default VPC?